# Converting a month and year to a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app I receive a month and a year from the user which I would like to make into a date. The new date should be the 1st of the following month but I'm not sure on the best way to tackle this.

At the moment I have

```
expiry = Date.new(params[:expYear],params[:expMonth].to_i + 1,1)
```

but this isn't ideal because if someone entered 12 as the month my approach would make the month 13 which of course doesn't exist (and also the year wouldn't get updated either).

Are there any useful functions that could help here?

Comment: what are `:expYear` and `:expMonth`?  why do you need to add something to this?

Comment: they are data about a payment card

Comment: right, but what values is the user putting in to those fields?  why do you have to add something to it?  they're not putting in the actual expiration date?

Comment: the user will be entering typical values like you or I would if we were to be adding details of a credit card - an integer for expiry month and another for expiry year. I want it as a date form for easy comparison

Comment: i understand that - so why do you need to add something to it?

Comment: Well I'm making the assumption that to store a date in Ruby/Rails I need to provide three parameters (year, month and day) - is this the case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38686/discussion-between-tommyd456-and-dax)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
year,month = params[:expYear].to_i,params[:expMonth].to_i

Date.new(year,month) + 1.month
```

or use the [end_of_month](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/end_of_month) as @dax wrote:

```
Date.new(year,month).end_of_month + 1.day
```

That will resolve your problem

Comment: thanks for this - I just worked it out as you posted

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be more simple

```
expiry = Date.new(params[:expYear],params[:expMonth].to_i).next_month
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this - sorry just before your answer user2503775

```
expiry = Date.new(params[:expYear].to_i,params[:expMonth].to_i) + 1.month
```

**Note** You have to convert to integers before this can be done. I also found out that if the day param is left out it defaults to 1 anyway so that's handy

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
Date.new(params[:expYear].to_i,params[:expMonth].to_i,1).advance(months: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
Time.zone.local(params[:expYear].to_i, params[:expMonth].to_i, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```